# Linking Fortran Modules Together

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I have a project where I have my main file and two modules in their own files such that main.f95, mod1.f95, mod2.f95. Initially, I designed my Makefile to run in this fashion

```
# PROGRAM NAME
main = main

# MODULE NAME
mod1 = mod1
mod2 = mod2
########################################
cmplr = gfortran
flags = -g -Wall

objects1 = $(mod1).o    $(mod2).o       $(main).o

$(main)     :   $(objects1)
                $(cmplr) $(flags) -o $(main) $(objects1)

$(mod1).o   :   $(mod1).f95
                $(cmplr) -c $(mod1).f95

$(mod2).o   :   $(mod2).f95
                $(cmplr) -c $(mod2).f95

$(main).o   :   $(main).f95 $(mod1).f95 $(mod2).f95
                $(cmplr) -c $(main).f95

clean           :
                rm -f *.mod *.pcl *.pc *.o $(main) *.inc *.vo *.d *.out
```

This has worked for my initial design, but now my project's complexity is getting to the point where mod1 will be used in mod2 and the main file, so I need to relink the files.

I tried this change to the Makefile

```
$(mod2).o   :   $(mod2).f95      $(mod1).f95
                $(cmplr) -c $(mod2).f95
```

I essentially followed how the main.o compilation structure is defined in the Makefile and followed that design since it seemed similar, but it doesn't seem to work for me trying to link mod1 into mod2. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you try with `$(mod1).f95 $(mod2).f95`? `make` does not "detect" the dependencies. I warmy recommend [cmake](https://cmake.org/) anyway :-)

Comment: Since you're using GFortran, I recommend the approach I described (just a few hours ago) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883160/75652

Comment: Wow, as simple as switching the order allowed it to compile. My mistake to forget to try something so simple. Thank you for the help and information!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the Makefile will compile if the order is switched such that

```
$(mod2).o   :   $(mod1).f95      $(mod2).f95
                $(cmplr) -c $(mod2).f95
```